# Filas de un datagrid en WPF Usando SQLite

Tags: c#, wpf

Por favor Necesito saber ¿Como puedo borrar una fila de un datagrid conectado a una base de datos utilizando SQLite? Gracias de antemano espero sus ayudas. Soy Nuevo en WPF y estoy sumamente perdido con muchos metodos aun. Se le agradece mucho de su ayuda.[image: Error Eliminar Filas en DataGrid]

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Colocar urgente no logrará atraer la atención deseada a tu pregunta, por favor lee [ask], edita y agrega lo que has intentado, las dudas puntuales y el resultado esperado

Comment: Hola porque no borras tu elemento del listado que carga la grilla?

Comment: A ver, si se carga con una consulta SQL y borras un elemento, lo lógico es que borres el item en la BD y vuelvas a cargar el DataGrid... Ahora bien yendo más profundo, hay que ver si ese botón lo tienes 1 vez para borrar el item seleccionado, o lo tienes repetido en cada fila.. en el primer caso deberías hacer esto: DetalleDataGrid.Items.Remove(DetalleDataGrid.SelectedItem); y en el segundo caso: object obj = ((Button)sender).DataContext; 
 DetalleDataGrid.Items.Remove(obj); y listo.